# ComboBox on Userform Runtime Error "13"

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, userform

On my code below, I have an Runtime Error 13 (type missmatch). I don't know what the problem is? I have tried to fill the combobox with the sheet names.
The error appears on UserForm_Activate().

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet

    ComboBox2.Clear

    For Each xSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ComboBox2.AddItem xSheet.Name
    Next xSheet
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lblName As String
    Dim lblDate As String

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce, works fine for me.

Comment: do you think it could have problems with the rest of the code?

Comment: I also can't reproduce, was there any specific line or part of the code highlighted when you click 'Debug'?

Comment: I voted to close the question because it cannot be reproduced anymore.

Answer (score 0):

All right the problem was, that I had a Excel 5.0 Dialog sheet which I had to delete for the combobox not to crash. 
Thanks to @dwirony you brought me to the idea!